# I need to send email using PHP, How can I install smtp server on my PC( windows XP)?

Tags: php, smtp

I have installed apache-5.4.2, PHP-5.4.11 and Mysql-5.5.29 . I want to send mail using php. I have realized that I need a SMTP server on my PC in order to send mails. Can anyone please tell me the details on how to install a SMTP server to send mail. Please give me details on it as I am new to this. Just FYI I am using the below code in PHP.  Thanks.

```
<?php
$to = "xyz@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "abc@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to install an SMTP server on your own PC - in this case you should be using gmail's own servers.

Comment: Normally you'd use the smtp server from your own ISP.

Comment: I am using [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=functionality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have access to a standard email address, then you don't need an SMTP server on your pc, you simply need to setup your details in the php.ini.

If you open your php.ini file, and find this section;

```
[mail function]
SMTP = [Enter You Email SMTP address e.g. smtp.mymail.com]
smtp_port = 25

sendmail_from = [Enter your From Email Address e.g. me@mymail.com]

auth_username = [Enter your Email Address UserName e.g. me1234] 
auth_password = [Enter your Email Address Password e.g. password1234]
```

If you enter in the values supplied for your regular email address (without the square brackets!), Restart your WebServer and PHP, then you should be up and running...

**EDIT:**

Seems as though GMAIL / Google Apps requires SSL to send email.

As such, there's a StackOverflow Question here.. [How do I Send email using Gmail through mail() ? Where do I put the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380051/how-do-i-send-email-using-gmail-through-mail-where-do-i-put-the-password)

A full tutorial is here... http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

That has a full tutorial for sending email via gmail and PHPMailer. An excerpt from this is;

---

**1)** If you don’t have one, register a GMail account or setup your domain
    for Google applications.

**2)** Download a recent version of PHPMailer (I’m using the version 5.02)

**3)** Check with your web hosting provider that port 465 (TCP out) is
    open, if not ask him to open that port

**4)** Include the PHPMailer class file:

```
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

**5)** Create those two constant variables to store your GMail login and
    password. Use the login for your Google Apps mail account if you
    have one.

```
define('GUSER', 'you@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD', 'password'); // GMail password
```

**6)** Use the following function to send the e-mail messages (add the
    function in one of your included files):

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Most of the settings inside the function are required by GMail. While searching for PHPmailer tutorials I found articles with different settings for the port and security. My advice is to use the settings from this tutorial.

**7)** Call the function within your code:

```
smtpmailer('to@mail.com', '', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!');
```

Use this more “advanced” usage inside your application:

```
if (smtpmailer('to@mail.com', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!')) {
    // do something
}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
```

Comment: Thanks to you PGallagher for the reply, I have done as instructed by you but I am facing the same issue , the error when i execute in the browser is:- /* Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Apache\htdocs\php.php on line 7 Mail Sent. */

Comment: Also I have checked on command prompt that I am able to successfully ping by the following command "ping smtp.gmail.com" but the following command fails "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" and the error is "connecting to smtp.gmail.com.. could not open connection to the host,on port 25: connection failed"

Comment: Please note I have diabled firewall and is there something else I can do, also PHP code is as I have mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: Looking at this, for gmail, you may need to refer to this post... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10380118/1305169. As it looks like gmail requires SSL to operate...

Comment: A full tutorial is here... http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: please note that I have made the above mentioned changed by you and also enables a ssl module in php.ini file and it has worked . Thanks a lot for your help !!! :) :). This was very helpful and i guess it will also be for the newbies. Thanks once again.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad I could help! Feel free to mark the answer! :-D

Answer (score 0):

On XP, some years ago, I used to install [Argosoft Mini MailServer](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/Download.aspx).

I preferred it to gmail or external ones because I can see SMTP logs. Just define your smtp as `localhost` in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks to you for the reply, I have done as instructed by you but I am facing the same issue , the error when i execute in the browser is:- /* Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Apache\htdocs\php.php on line 7 Mail Sent. */

Comment: Also I have checked on command prompt that I am able to successfully ping by the following command "ping smtp.gmail.com" but the following command fails "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" and the error is "connecting to smtp.gmail.com.. could not open connection to the host,on port 25: connection failed"Please note I have diabled firewall and is there something else I can do, also PHP code is as I have mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure php.ini file to send email via php send mail function.

1. Open php.ini file.

Default php.ini file settings

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

these entries are required to send the mail to any mail client from mail server.

2.The following two lines don't exist:

auth_username
auth_password

you need to add them to send mail from a server that requires authentication.

1. change SMTP settings

smtp_server = mail.example.com ///your SMTP server name.
smtp_port = 26 // SMTP port number
auth_username = username@example.com
auth_password = password
sendmail_from = you@example.com // from email address.

4.SAVE php.ini file.

1. Restart Server.
2. DONE.

Comment: Thanks to you Dasun for the reply, I have done as instructed by you but I am facing the same issue , the error when i execute in the browser is:- /* Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Apache\htdocs\php.php on line 7 Mail Sent. */

Comment: Also I have checked on command prompt that I am able to successfully ping by the following command "ping smtp.gmail.com" but the following command fails "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" and the error is "connecting to smtp.gmail.com.. could not open connection to the host,on port 25: connection failed"

Comment: Please note I have diabled firewall and is there something else I can do, also PHP code is as I have mentioned above. Thanks